# Creating a job-array from text file for Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a job array to run simultaneously taking each line from the text file "somemore.txt" where I have the directories of some files I want to run through the program "fastqc". This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -N QC
#$ -cwd
#$ -l h_vmem=24G
cd /emc/cbmr/users/czs772/
FILENAME=$(sed -n $SGE_TASK_ID"p" somemore.txt)
/home/czs772/FastQC/fastqc $FILENAME -outdir /emc/cbmr/users/czs772/marcQC
```

but I get the error: "No such file or directory"

instead, if I run the code through a for loop I have no error:

```
for name in $(cat /emc/cbmr/users/czs772/somemore.txt) 
do /home/czs772/FastQC/fastqc $name -outdir /emc/cbmr/users/czs772/marcQC 
done
```

So it makes me think that the mistake is the script code and not the directory, but I can't make it to work. I've also tried to open the file with "cat" but again, it didn't work.

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you run it with $SGE_TASK_ID set?

Comment: The quoting in FILENAME=$(sed -n $SGE_TASK_ID"p" somemore.txt) doesn't look right,

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I typed "cat -vet" to see hidden characters:

```
cat -vet 2fastqc.sh

#!/bin/bash^M$
#$ -S /bin/bash^M$
#$ -N FastQC^M$
#$ -cwd^M$
#$ -pe smp 1^M$
#$ -l h_vmem=12G^M$
^M$
cd /emc/cbmr/users/czs772/^M$
FILENAME=$(sed -n $SGE_TASK_ID"p" somemore.txt)^M$
/home/czs772/FastQC/fastqc $FILENAME -outdir marcQC
```

Which showed an "^M" at the end of each line, I just discovered this is something that may happen when writing scripts in windows. It can be solved:

- from the code editor program (I use Sublime text): by selecting the code, View tab -> Line Endings -> Unix (instead of Windows)
- from the server by typing: dos2unix [name of the script.sh]

Thanks for your comments!